# Progress for individual achievements in Steam?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam, achievements

Is it possible to see progress for individual achievements in Steam?

For example in Skyrim, there's the achievement "Delver" (clear 50 dungeons), and we're wondering what number we're at.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Steam doesn't show your progress for the achievements in Skyrim.

However, you can track your progress via the ingame general stats section. Those numbers are synched with steam to unlock your achievements.

Comment: Thanks, this turned out to be the answer. Perhaps you could  add a note to your answer that "No, you can't check it in Steam, only in game."

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the game.

Most of the time, yes.

I know there are a few achievements for Team Fortress 2 that don't display correctly on your Steam profile, but do through the in-game achievement interface.

Achievements that require a lot of doing something usually have some sorts of milestones that pop up.

Comment: "Most of the time, yes" but where then? For the mentioned achievement I could not find progress in Steam, only in the game itself.

Comment: It depends on the game and how tightly it's integrated with Steam. Some games like Skyrim only send "Achievement completed" messages. Others - mostly Valve games - send more detailed info to Steam so it can show progress `3/5`. I _believe_ that any came could take advantage of the progress info. I assume that games written for multiple platforms like xbox/ps just reuse as much code as possible so only worry about a single "achieved" message.